# Multiple columns select using where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select
    CustomerName,City,State, MatchId,ServingSize, Fruit, DarkGreen, 
    [Red/Orange], Legumes, Starchy, Other, [Grains (oz)], 
    [Whole51%orgreater?], [Meat / Meat Alt], [Fluid Milk (cups)], Calories, 
    [Sodium (MG)], [Saturated Fat (grams)], [Trans Fat (grams)],
    MeetsAllianceForAHealthierGenerationGuidelines, OtherNotes, Name, 
    WebsiteLinkToSource, Date
from
    #FinalTempTable
Where 
    (
        MatchId,ServingSize, Fruit, DarkGreen, [Red/Orange], Legumes, Starchy, 
        Other, [Grains (oz)], [Whole51%orgreater?], [Meat / Meat Alt], [Fluid Milk (cups)],
        Calories, [Sodium (MG)], [Saturated Fat (grams)], [Trans Fat (grams)],
        MeetsAllianceForAHealthierGenerationGuidelines, OtherNotes, Name,
        WebsiteLinkToSource, Date
    )
    IN 
    (
        Select
            MatchId,ServingSize, Fruit, DarkGreen, [Red/Orange], Legumes, 
            Starchy, Other, [Grains (oz)], [Whole51%orgreater?], [Meat / Meat Alt], 
            [Fluid Milk (cups)],Calories, [Sodium (MG)], [Saturated Fat (grams)], 
            [Trans Fat (grams)], MeetsAllianceForAHealthierGenerationGuidelines, 
            OtherNotes, Name, WebsiteLinkToSource, Date
        From
            MealContributions 
        Where
            MatchId IN (Select distinct MatchId from #FinalTempTable)
    )
```

I am using this query but it gives the following error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 An expression of non-boolean
>   type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

I want all the columns from #finaltemptable and only those columns of mealcontributions whose MatchId is same as #finaltemptable matchid

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your where clause doesn't make any sense, it should be in the form `WHERE [some boolean condition]`, not a list of columns.

Comment: man, your syntax is messed up

Comment: Hi Bridge, I want to select CustomerName,City,State, columns from #FinalTempTable and other columns MatchId,ServingSize, Fruit, DarkGreen, 
                [Red/Orange], Legumes, Starchy, Other, [Grains (oz)], 
                [Whole51%orgreater?], [Meat / Meat Alt], [Fluid Milk (cups)], Calories, 
                [Sodium (MG)], [Saturated Fat (grams)], [Trans Fat (grams)],
    MeetsAllianceForAHealthierGenerationGuidelines, OtherNotes, Name, 
    WebsiteLinkToSource, Date     from New table MealContributions

Comment: your query doesn't do anything.  it searches a table for values in the same table.

Comment: Then Please help that how I will select other columns from second table

Comment: @user1634579 Please edit your original post with the table structures, some sample data from each table and what you you expect the result to be.  Providing this info will be very helpful in answering your question.

Comment: It is a large SP of 1000 lines and this is a small part. I am asking that (1)I have a temp table from which I select some columns.  (2) Some other columns I want to select from second table.  Please check this link what I want http://www.baskent.edu.tr/~tkaracay/etudio/ders/dbase/sql/htmSQL/OracleDers12.htm     Using Multiple-Column Subqueries.

Comment: Hi Beth,  Please check it once again so that I can get my answer and work on the project using this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form

```
Where 
        (MatchId,ServingSize, Fruit, ... other columns .... ) 
IN 
        (... subquery with columns ...)
```

works in MySQL, but not in SQL Server.

You'd have to make up an EXISTS clause with ALL the matching columns listed out.

```
 select CustomerName, City, State, MatchId, ServingSize, Fruit, DarkGreen, 
        [Red/Orange], Legumes, Starchy, Other, [Grains (oz)], 
        [Whole51%orgreater?], [Meat / Meat Alt], [Fluid Milk (cups)], Calories, 
        [Sodium (MG)], [Saturated Fat (grams)], [Trans Fat (grams)],
        MeetsAllianceForAHealthierGenerationGuidelines, OtherNotes, Name, 
        WebsiteLinkToSource, Date
   from #FinalTempTable f
  where exists (
        select *
          from MealContributions m
         where f.matchid = m.matchid AND
               f.ServingSize = m.ServingSize AND
               .... all the columns! ...)
```

The last condition

```
Where MatchId IN (Select distinct MatchId from #FinalTempTable))
```

Is extraneous since you're already matching `f.matchid = m.matchid`.

Comment: It gives error with MealContributions table's columns(ServingSize, Fruit, DarkGreen, 
        [Red/Orange], Legumes, Starchy, Other, [Grains (oz)], 
        [Whole51%orgreater?], [Meat / Meat Alt], [Fluid Milk (cups)], Calories, 
        [Sodium (MG)], [Saturated Fat (grams)], [Trans Fat (grams)],
        MeetsAllianceForAHealthierGenerationGuidelines, OtherNotes, Name, 
        WebsiteLinkToSource, Date) that Multipart Identifier could not be bound.

Comment: I want all the columns from #finaltemptable and only those columns of mealcontributions whose MatchId is same as #finaltemptable matchid. But I don't want to use any join.